# Prove that there exists a machine which decides an infinite subset of halting problem

Tags: computability, turing-machines, halting-problem

We already know that $H:=\{\langle M,w\rangle | M$ halts on $w\}$ is undecidable, then how can there possibly be a machine that decides any infinite subset of $H$?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: Hint: There are infinitely many machines for which the halting problem is trivial.

Comment: $L=\{\langle M, w\rangle|M$ halts on $w$ in less than 10 steps$\}$.

Comment: It's probably easiest to visualize this in terms of some code in your favorite programming language. Is there a simple algorithm you can write that can correctly diagnose that a (say) Python script is of a particular never-halting form? Sure. Consider any valid program that starts with the string "while True: x=1;", of which there are infinitely many (e.g the next line could be "a=1", or "a=2", or "a=3", etc.). Such a program never halts and is easy to identify.

Answer (score 1):

Let $M$ be a TM which accepts all inputs. Then $\{ \langle M, w \rangle \mid w \in \{ 0, 1 \}^\ast \}$ is an infinite subset of $H$ and (easily) decidable.

Going further, let $M_w$ be a TM which halts if and only if its input is not equal to $w \in \{ 0, 1 \}^\ast$ and let it be such that $\langle M_w \rangle$ is computable from any $w$ (e.g., $w$ is a substring of the description of $M_w$). Then the set $\{ \langle M_w, w' \rangle \mid w, w' \in \{ 0, 1 \}^\ast \}$ is another infinite subset of $H$ which is decidable. The description for a decider could be, for example: Given $\langle M_w, w' \rangle$, compute $\langle M_{w'} \rangle$ and accept if and only if it is equal to $\langle M_w \rangle$.

**A warning**: in the question text you referred to "a machine that decides any infinite subset of $H$". Indeed, no such machine exists (since $H$ is an infinite subset of itself); however, this is not what the question title (presumably the intended question) is implying.